# Error 403 Forbidden in Whatsapp Business API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, whatsapp, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to implement whatsapp business API but I'm getting forbidden error I think its because i dont have enough permission.
I have also implemented this code on Postman its works fine there but its not working in app i dont know why?

```
var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/110474688636083/messages");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer EAAM2wERIcIsBAFSGQD3yCSYRd5II5u7hU1859z8VcpNFlZBjJrqJUR2QrgZADHlHYSCG0zWvpYqVkFlzea9TsN1wnu8ZBZBSiEaXQu5OZAQC63ufVKZAQDHZB25CIq3TBQ9rxr2DdZB1oZBgJtia4eAEBbzqfjwJpXm9M5SZCGhDh7JbK0s1ldz2Od099jHfKrFvnQDZD");
        var content = new StringContent("{\n    \"messaging_product\": \"whatsapp\",\n    \"to\": \""+WHATSAPPNO+"\",\n    \"type\": \"template\",\n    \"template\": {\n        \"name\": \"hello_world\",\n        \"language\": {\n            \"code\": \"en_US\"\n        }\n    }\n}", null, "application/json");
        request.Content = content;
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

thank you for your time

Comment: Did you copy the code from postman?

Comment: yes i did copy the code from postman

Comment: if you wrap your code in a try catch block, the request might throw a "WebException", this class has a Response property. Mine had a json with "TLS versions older than v1.2 are not supported" inside.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the access token.

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer TOKEN");
```

`TOKEN` here is an placeholder and not a real token

Comment: i have added TOKEN and the phone num but the issue is still there

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to resolve your issue,

- JSON is not in correct format in your code.

Model files,

```
public class Language
{
    public string code { get; set; }
}

public class WhatsAppDataModel
{
    public string messaging_product { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Template template { get; set; }
}

public class Template
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Language language { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need two packages RestClient and Newtonsoft.Json,
Main c# class function,

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/110474688636083/messages";
Uri baseUri = new Uri(url);

IRestClient client = new RestClient(baseUri)
IRestRequest request = new RestRequest("", Method.Post);

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

Language lang = new Language();
lang.code = "en_US";

Template template = new Template();
template.name = "hello_world";
template.language = lang;

WhatsAppDataModel whatsapp = new WhatsAppDataModel();
whatsapp.messaging_product = "whatsapp";
whatsapp.to = "<whatsappNumber>";
whatsapp.type = "template";
whatsapp.template = template;

string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(whatsapp);

request.AddParameter("application/json", body , ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

facebook graph API latest version is v16.0 and not v15.0. So try updating that might also help you.

[Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/)

Format is change for sending message in v16.0 [check this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/overview/)

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages' \
  -H "Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  -d '{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "1650XXXXXXX",
    "text": {"body" : "hi"}
   }'
```